# Multiple videos with multiple classes used in one js function

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

That title is quite confusing, I know.

So briefly, I have 5 videos and want them all to use js to play AND pause them individually onclick.

Each video has a different class, but I've given them all a second class to group them together. (to my knowledge)

my js :

```
var myVideo = document.getElementByClassName("videos"); 

function playPause() { 
    if (myVideo.paused) 
        myVideo.play(); 
    else 
        myVideo.pause(); 
}
```

my html: (all 5 videos are idential html except the id's)

```
        <div class="video1">
            <video id="video1" class="videos video1" width="500" height="303" onclick="playPause();">
                <source src="hlace.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="hlace.ogg" type="video/ogg">
            </video>
        </div>
```

I've used `.getElementById` and the js has worked for the video which Id I used. But now I want to apply it for all the videos and I'm stumped.

https://jsfiddle.net/jomot/1jvq1myf/

Comment: Can you add a code snippet for your code or you can add a jsfiddle link as well

Comment: @harsheet1 will make an edit to post with jsfiddle link now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like below -

Your js fiddle code has many errors due to the videos and the main error is -

This

```
var myVideo = document.getElementByClassName("videos");
```

should be changed to

```
var myVideo = document.getElementsByClassName("videos");
```

The below code will give you an idea of what you need to do. You can simply pass this.id to playpause() function. This way it will only work on the div that is clicked and not on others. By doing this, there is no need to group the elements that you have done in your code by giving the same css class to all div elements.

Hope this helps!

```js
function playPause(id) { 
var divId = document.getElementById(id);
     if (divId.getAttribute('status') == 'paused') {
         divId.setAttribute('status', 'play');
         divId.play(); 
     }
    else{
     divId.setAttribute('status', 'paused');
      divId.pause(); 
    }
  }
```

```css
.responsive {
    padding: 0 6px;
    width: 24.99999%;
 margin-left: 20%;
 }

@media only screen and (max-width: 1700px){
    .responsive {
        width: 49.99999%;
        margin-left: 5%;
  }
 }

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px){
    .responsive {
  width: 24.99999%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  }
 }
 
div.video1 {
 margin-left: 26%;
 margin-bottom: 1%;
 display: inline-block;
   }
   
div.video2 {
 margin-left: 26%;
 margin-bottom: 1%;
 display: inline-block;
   }
   
div.video3 {
 margin-left: 26%;
 margin-bottom: 1%;
 display: inline-block;
   }

div.video4 {
 margin-left: 26%;
 margin-bottom: 1%;
 display: inline-block;
   }

div.video5 {
 margin-left: 26%;
 margin-bottom: 10%;
 display: inline-block;
   }
```

```html
<div class="background">
 <div class="transbox">
  <hr>
  <h2> Highlights </h2>
  <hr>
  
  <div class="responsive">
  <div class="video1">
   <video id="video1" class="videos video1" status="paused" width="500" height="303" onclick="playPause(this.id);">
    <source src="hlace.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="hlace.ogg" type="video/ogg">
   </video>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="responsive">
  <div class="video2">
   <video id="video2" class="videos video2" status="paused" width="500" height="300" onclick="playPause(this.id);">
    <source src="hldustace.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="hldustace.ogg" type="video/ogg">
   </video>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="responsive">
  <div class="video3">
   <video id="video3" class="videos video3" status="paused" width="500" height="300" onclick="playPause(this.id);">
    <source src="hlflick.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="hlflick.ogg" type="video/ogg">
   </video>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="responsive">
  <div class="video4">
   <video id="video4" class="videos video4" status="paused" width="500" height="300" onclick="playPause(this.id);">
    <source src="hlmirage.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="hlmirage.ogg" type="video/ogg">
   </video>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="responsive">
  <div class="video5">
   <video id="video5" class="videos video5" status="paused" width="500" height="300" onclick="playPause(this.id)">
    <source src="hlreel.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="hlreel.ogg" type="video/ogg">
   </video>
  </div>
  </div>
  
 </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Heyy, glad it worked for you! You can give it a vote up as well :)